# How to set this strange anim. keys in outliner?

Tags: animation, scripting, keyframes, outliner

I'd like to set animation keys from python script (for automatization). In this particular case can't find command for outliner context. I need command to set keys for 'TOGVIZ' and 'TOGREN'. (Not by picking that pictograms.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The little camera and eye icons you use to change visibility in the outliner are toggling object properties.

The eye icon links to the [`hide`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.hide) property, while the camera icon links to the `hide_render` property and the cursor is the `hide_select` property.

To insert keyframes using python you set the property and then use [`keyframe_insert`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) to create a keyframe with that value.

```
obj = bpy.context.object

obj.hide = True
obj.keyframe_insert('hide', frame=1)
obj.hide = False
obj.keyframe_insert('hide', frame=10)

obj.hide_render = True
obj.keyframe_insert('hide_render', frame=1)
obj.hide_render = False
obj.keyframe_insert('hide_render', frame=10)
```